# Haskell type declarations

Tags: haskell, types

In Haskell, why does this compile:

```
splice :: String -> String -> String
splice a b = a ++ b
main = print (splice "hi" "ya")
```

but this does not:

```
splice :: (String a) => a -> a -> a
splice a b = a ++ b
main = print (splice "hi" "ya")

>> Type constructor `String' used as a class
```

I would have thought these were the same thing.  Is there a way to use the second style, which avoids repeating the type name 3 times?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `=>` syntax in types is for [typeclasses](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/using-typeclasses.html).

When you say `f :: (Something a) => a`, you aren't saying that `a` *is* a `Something`, you're saying that it is a type "in the group of" `Something` types.

For example, `Num` is a typeclass, which includes such types as `Int` and `Float`.
Still, there is no type `Num`, so I can't say

```
f :: Num -> Num
f x = x + 5
```

However, I could either say

```
f :: Int -> Int
f x = x + 5
```

or

```
f :: (Num a) => a -> a
f x = x + 5
```

Comment: I see, so the key difference then is that in my code, String is a *type* instead of a *typeclass*.  Thanks for clarifying that distinction for me.  I figured they could be used interchangeably.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, it is possible:

```
Prelude> :set -XTypeFamilies
Prelude> let splice :: (a~String) => a->a->a; splice a b = a++b
Prelude> :t splice
splice :: String -> String -> String
```

This uses the equational constraint `~`. But I'd avoid that, it's not really much shorter than simply writing `String -> String -> String`, rather harder to understand, and more difficult for the compiler to resolve.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "more difficult for the compiler to resolve"? That doesn't sound right on the face of it.

Comment: @DanielWagner: well, honestly I don't know how difficult it is for the compiler. I just have a feeling there is more to it then simply a local `type A = String` synonym.

Comment: I will feel more comfortable voting for this answer if you remove the FUD.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way to use the second style, which avoids repeating the type name 3 times?

For simplifying type signatures, you may use type synonyms. For example you could write

```
type S = String
splice :: S -> S -> S
```

or something like

```
type BinOp a = a -> a -> a
splice :: BinOp String
```

however, for something as simple as `String -> String -> String`, I recommend just typing it out. Type synonyms should be used to make type signatures more readable, not less.

In this particular case, you could also generalize your type signature to

```
splice :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
```

since it doesn't depend on the elements being characters at all.

Comment: Another very helpful answer, thanks!  The yield of instructive answers has been very high for me on this question.

Answer (score 1):

Well... `String` is a type, and you were trying to use it as a class.

If you want an example of a polymorphic version of your `splice` function, try:

```
import Data.Monoid

splice :: Monoid a=> a -> a -> a
splice = mappend
```

*EDIT*: so the syntax here is that Uppercase words appearing left of `=>` are *type classes* constraining variables that appear to the right of `=>`. All the Uppercase words to the right are names of *types*

Answer (score 1):

You might find explanations in [this Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/types-and-typeclasses) chapter handy.

Comment: Actually it was precisely that chapter that triggered my question.  Based on that chapter's examples, which used Integral instead of String, I expected the above code to compile.

Comment: You can try this at the ghci prompt to get an idea of the difference between these things. ghci> :type Integral -- this should give an error. ghci> :info Integral -- this will give you the class definition for Integral. Now try that with String.